# Android eclipse plugin

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

I am looking into using android plugin in eclipse.
I can't understand the instructions:

> Once Eclipse restarts, you must specify the location of your Android
>   SDK directory:
>
> In the "Welcome to Android Development" window that appears, select
>   Use existing SDKs. **Browse and select the location of the Android SDK
>   directory you recently downloaded and unpacked**. Click Next.

What recently downloaded SDK?

Comment: You should have downloaded some SDKs through the SDK manager, but if not, you can open the SDK Manager and download it right now. That being said, I went down this path, and ultimately I switched to Android Studio, which IMO is much better and is also what many guides on the net reference when doing things.

Comment: Slow down there. ADT plugin is no longer supported. Start using Android Studio. It is the official IDE of Android.

Comment: I always preferred the ADT Bundle, rather than installing Eclipse and then the ADT. One package, one setup. Apart the SDK updates, of course.

Comment: @JaredBurrows:But what is the difference?Isn't the Android Studio the Eclipse with the plugins but pre-setup?

Comment: Why use unsupported software? Please read: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: @JaredBurrows: Because I am confortable with eclipse and would like to start looking into android using an IDE I am familiar with. But I can't figure out how to do that so far :(

Comment: @Jim I understand that but you will find less and less support for an IDE that is no longer support with Android. You should go to the link I provided, download Android Studio and it will take of the SDK downloading for you.

Comment: @JaredBurrows:So it will contain the SDK for eclipse and be able to use android studio if I decide to give it  a try?

Comment: The link contains everything. It is obvious you have not even made it that far.

Comment: @JaredBurrows (Leaving Jim out since he will be notified as the post owner, anyway) Android Studio is based on [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) which has been out-growing Eclipse in popularity recently, and for good reason. Once you understand how Gradle works (and how it automatically updates for you), you'll never want to go back. Also note: [the Eclipse plugin has been officially killed by Google](http://www.zdnet.com/article/google-releases-android-studio-kills-off-eclipse-adt-plugin/). If you want your new Android skills to be relevant, you should be using Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to just install the ADT bundle, it comes with the SDK, ADT and eclipse all bundled together. So all you have to do is download, unpack, install some packages and run eclipse..
here is the URL  developer.android.com/sdk/

Comment: Or just install Android Studio, since Eclipse is getting less and less support

Comment: What am I supposed to download from this link?When I pressed "Download Android Studio" I got an IDE that is not eclipse. How can I get the bundle with eclipse?

Comment: @jim, Are you trying to download android studio or the eclipse ADT bundle

Comment: The eclipse ADT.I thought that there would be some donwload that has everything (eclipse+SDK etc) included and configured